# Scroll product image while description stay

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, shopify

Currently my product page https://holly-tanager.myshopify.com/products/the-professional?variant=37949126862, when you scroll through the photos on the product pages on the left, the copy on the right will not show in entirety until you get through all photos. We would like for the copy to be more easily accessible so that consumers don’t have to scroll multiple times on the left to view the full copy on the product page. I really like how the Cuyana product pages function. https://www.cuyana.com/classic-structured-leather-tote.html#caramel-navy .

Anyone can help me home this page works https://www.cuyana.com/classic-structured-leather-tote.html#caramel-navy.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you show us what have you tried to do yourself in regards to this request?

Comment: This how to create a collage like this https://hollyandtanager.com/trailblazers/ using only css, js, jquery. Thanks.